# Static resource URL in Drupal 8 theme

Tags: theming, 8, uri

I'm trying to place an image using a local resource in theme. Using the site url like

```
drupal.localhost/themes/customtheme/images/image.png
```

does give me access denied error. I understand that Drupal should generate a public url for the image, but how to ask Drupal to do so from the theme while still using relative URLs in `src` tag of `img` ?

edit: Changed question, made more clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [file_create_url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/8) function:

Example of usage in a preprocess hook:

```
$variables['image'] = file_create_url($variables['directory'] . '/images/image.png');
```

Example of usage in a twig template:

```
 <img src="{{ file_url(directory ~ '/images/image.png') }}"/>
```

Comment: is there no such funcion for twig ?

Comment: file_create_url is supposed to work as per the documentation but its also not producing a web accesible url.

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/node/2396439 @पंचतत्वम्

Comment: @Clive file_url also outputs url of the form drupal.localhost/themes/customtheme/images/image.png . This is not publicly accessible. Its supposed to create publically accesible urls. But it doesn't.

Comment: @Clive It turns out that the URL produced by file_url is indeed web accessible. I had permissions issue on the server. Setting it 0777, which is not recommended; i'm looking for better permissions, resolved it.