# In Drupal 8 how do I get the image path from a twig node template?

Tags: theming, 8

I'm working with Drupal 8 and twig

I created a Drupal content type called hero. It contains a title, body copy and an image. I'm overwriting node.html.twig for this content type but am having trouble accessing the image source to generate html I need to.

```
<div {{ attributes.addClass(classes) }} style="background-image: url(/img/site/about/about_hero_banner.jpg);">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <div class="copy">
            <h1>
              Headline
            </h1>
            <p>
              Subhead Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, sed voluptatum fugit ipsa animi quos nobis?
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I can access the Headline and title with the code below but I don't want to load the image file I want only want the image path (source).

```
{{ content.body }}
{{ content.field_headline }}
{{ content.field_hero_image }}
```

How do I get the image file path from in my node template from 
{{ content.field_hero_image }}? How do I access the attributes of content.field_hero_image?

I've looked at image.html.twig and see

```
<img{{ attributes }} />
```

So I know it's in the attributes, but don't know how to access the attributes from the node template.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static resource URL in Drupal 8 theme](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188819/static-resource-url-in-drupal-8-theme)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this question is actually different. It's looking for the image src in a node template. I posted an answered below.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, after writing this question a similar one showed up and I think I found the solution:

```
{{ file_url(node.field_hero_image.entity.fileuri) }}
```